# Who is "he" in the passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronoun-dropping

> On Monday, October 13, 2014 about 09:30 hours John Barlow - Male Negro,  Age 22 years A Joiner of Lot 194 Pike street Kitty, Georgetown, reported that Mark Jacobs Male Negro, Age 22 years unemployed of abeam, dealt him several cuts on his face with a knife at church St Georgetown, due to a misunderstanding over money **he** had borrowed a week ago.

Who is "he" in the passage?

Comment: *John Barlow* reported that *Mark Jacobs* dealt him (John) several cuts on his (John's) face with a knife, due to a misunderstanding over money he (probably John, but can't tell from just the pronoun) had borrowed a week ago. Look to the preceding or following sentence(s) for more context. Also please feel take a few minutes to visit the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily clear from the syntax alone here.

We can assume that *he* applies to John Barlow for two reasons:

1. John Barlow is clearly the *him* prior to that, and as such the most recently mentioned person that the *he* could apply to.
2. It's more common in cases of a violent disagreement about a loan for the lender to attack the borrower.

Neither of these completely rule out the other possibility; the borrower might feel themselves aggrieved or at risk, and people do not always consistently follow the rule that pronouns refer to the last applicable person or thing when writing. It is therefore just about possible that the writer actually meant Mark Jacobs, but John Barlow is definitely the reading most readily given.

Comment: It is not clear from the syntax. However I am going for Mark Jacobs. As he is unemployed it would seem more likely to me that he would be the borrower. John Barlow seems to be in good employment as a skilled craftsman. I'm curious as to what "of abeam" means. Could it be American for "of no fixed address"?

Answer (score -1):

Here, John Barlow is reporting, and hence it says Mark Jacobs dealt a damage with the knife. Thus 'he' refers to John Barlow, as he had a misunderstanding with the borrowing matter.